# Simple Traffic Light Simulation with Java Threads

Tags: java, multithreading

As the questions states, I am trying to make a very, very simple traffic light simulation of a four way intersection. What my problem is, is that I am using two different threads and trying to bounce back and forth between the two using wait and notify *while inside a for loop.* I have some psuedo code below.

```
public class Processor 
{
    public static int CarCounter = 1;

    public void lightOneAndTwo() throws InterruptedException
    {
        synchronized(this)
        {
            for(int carsOne = 0; carsOne < 50; carsOne++)
            {
                //Light One---------------------------->


                //Light Two---------------------------->

                wait();
            }
        }
    }
    public void lightThreeAndFour() throws InterruptedException
    {
        Thread.sleep(1000);

        synchronized(this)
        {
            for(int carsTwo = 0; carsTwo < 50; carsTwo++ )
            {
                //Light Three---------------------------->

                notify();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when I call notify, it does not reactivate the the first thread. Am I doing something wrong or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Post a complete example.

Comment: notifyAll() is better

Comment: Problem seems like, your notify() call is wasted because you are simply calling it without any condition and it may run before even wait() is called on the same object.

Comment: You're not using a common lock object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program have multiple issues - no conditional variable, no while loop to check condition etc. Below is one possible solution. I have four classes:

> MyLock - (Lock Object)

```
package com.test;

public class MyLock {

    private volatile boolean condition;

    public MyLock(boolean condition) {
        this.condition = condition;
    }

    public boolean condition() {
        return condition;
    }

    public void flipCondition() {
        condition = !condition;
    }
}
```

> TrafficLightWorkerOne (Traffic Worker)

```
package com.test;

public class TrafficLightWorkerOne implements Runnable {

    private int cars;
    private MyLock lock;

    public TrafficLightWorkerOne(MyLock lock, int cars) {
        this.lock = lock;
        this.cars = cars;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            synchronized (lock) {
                while (!lock.condition()) {
                    for (int carsOne = 0; carsOne < cars; carsOne++) {

                        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()
                                + " car no : " + carsOne);
                        // Light One---------------------------->

                        // Light Two---------------------------->
                    }
                    lock.notifyAll();
                    lock.flipCondition();
                }
                try {
                    lock.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> TrafficLightWorkerTwo (Another Traffic Worker)

```
package com.test;

public class TrafficLightWorkerTwo implements Runnable {

    private int cars;
    private MyLock lock;

    public TrafficLightWorkerTwo(MyLock lock, int cars) {
        this.lock = lock;
        this.cars = cars;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        while (true) {
            synchronized (lock) {
                try {
                    while (!lock.condition()) {
                        lock.wait();
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                for (int carsOne = 0; carsOne < cars; carsOne++) {

                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()
                            + " car no : " + carsOne);
                    // Light One---------------------------->

                    // Light Two---------------------------->
                }
                lock.flipCondition();;
                lock.notifyAll();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

> TrafficLightSimulator (Main Class)

```
package com.test;

public class TrafficLightSimulator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean  condition = false; 
        MyLock lock = new MyLock(condition);
        Thread threadOne = new Thread(new TrafficLightWorkerOne(lock, 5), "One");
        Thread threadTwo = new Thread(new TrafficLightWorkerTwo(lock, 4), "Two");

        threadOne.start();
        threadTwo.start();

    }
}
```